# Is there a way to create Power BI Visuals using python?

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I know there is a way to create python visuals and make Power BI reports out of those visuals (matplotlib/sns). What I want to do is to make Power BI visuals using python. I'd like to automate the whole process.

I've a script that datamines and outputs dataframes and now I would like to see if automating the visualization process with Power Bi is possible using python.

Comment: Have you done any research already?

Answer (score 1):

Power BI allows creating visuals using Python and R scripts.

From visual pane, select python visual:

[image]

This will prompt you for enabling script visuals (if not already done), click enable.

[image]

It will open a script editor, however, you will not be able to write anything. To do so, plot the fields/measures you want to use in the script in the chart.

Find more info [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-python-visuals)